# Attempting to connect to SQL Server to query data using VBA but running into constant problems. Issues with code?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Here is the VBA code I have in the module:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim adoDBConn As New ADODB.connection
    Dim adoDbRs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim selectCmd As New ADODB.Command

    adoDBConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=LAPTOP-N0CT1GQ5;Initial Catalog=Interest_Analysis;User Id = ***;Password = ***;"

    selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDBConn
    selectCmd.CommandText = "County, cntyvtd, Name, Votes FROM 2020_General_Election_Returns_import_to_SQL"

    Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)

    Dim cellRange As Range
    Set cellRange = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Row.Count, 1)).EntireRow
    cellRange.ClearContents
    'The Worksheet tab is called "Data"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    ws.Activate

    If adoDbRs.EOF = False Then ws.Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset adoDbRs

    ws.Cells(1, 2) = "County"
    ws.Cells(1, 3) = "cntyvtd"
    ws.Cells(1, 4) = "Name"
    ws.Cells(1, 5) = "Votes"

    adoDbRs.Close
    Set adoDbRs = Nothing
    Set selectCmd = Nothing

    adoDBConn.Close
    Set adoDBConn = Nothing


End Sub
```

What I'm doing is using an ADODB connection to connect to SQL Server in Microsoft Excel and using VBA code to interact with the server so that the data can populate in an Excel sheet. I got much of the code template from a website, but have been running into a lot of errors and the debugger keeps pointing at different lines. Right now, it's pointing at the `Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute()` line and saying `Incorrect syntax near ','` and it would also go to the `If adoDbRs.EOF = False` and say `Object not found`. I might be missing a foundational statement or something I need to start with, so let me know what the issue is. Thank you!

To debug VBA and figure out how to pull SQL server data into an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Your SQL statement is missing a `Select`   and it should be `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)`

Comment: I did add SELECT before "County..." in the SQL statement and changed the other statement to Cells(Rows.Count, 1). However, it's still giving two constant errors. The first is: "Incorrect syntax near 2020" and points to: Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText). The second is: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed 3704" and points to: If adoDbRs.EOF = False Then

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me (against Oracle, but SQL server should work the same way)

```vb
Private Sub SOTest()

    Dim adoDBConn As New adodb.Connection
    Dim adoDbRs As adodb.Recordset 'no `New` here
    Dim selectCmd As New adodb.Command
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As adodb.Field

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    adoDBConn.Open "connection string here"

    selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDBConn
    selectCmd.CommandText = "select * from myTable"
    Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)

    'clear the output range
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 15)).ClearContents
    
    ResultsToSheet adoDbRs, ws.Cells(1, 2)
    
    ws.Activate
   
    adoDbRs.Close
    adoDBConn.Close
    
End Sub

'Place a recordset contents on a worksheet (incl. headers)
'  starting at `rng`
Sub ResultsToSheet(rs As adodb.Recordset, rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, f As adodb.Field
    Set c = rng.Cells(1) ' top left
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        c.Value = f.Name  'write the field header
        Set c = c.Offset(0, 1) 'next header cell
    Next f
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        'write the data starting on the next row
        rng.Cells(1).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
End Sub
```